In flutter getting error update_pressing_state(FlKeyEmbedderResponder
When I run my flutter app I am suddely getting the following error. Is there a way to trouble shoot why this issue is coming ?
CRITICAL **: 16:26:03.375: void update_pressing_state(FlKeyEmbedderResponder *, uint64_t, uint64_t): assertion 'lookup_hash_table(self->pressing_records, physical_key) != 0' failed

